# minBound and MaxBound in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
minmax1, minmax2, minmax3 :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
minBound :: Int = -9223372036854775808
maxBound :: Int = 9223372036854775807
minmax1 arr = (minimum(arr), maximum(arr))

main = do
    let list1 = [1, 2, 3]
    let list2 = [1, 9, 3]
    let list3 = [3, 2, 1, 0]
    let list4 = [100]
    let list5 = []
    putStrLn $ show list1 ++ " -> " ++ show (minmax1 list1)
    putStrLn $ show list2 ++ " -> " ++ show (minmax1 list2)
    putStrLn $ show list3 ++ " -> " ++ show (minmax1 list3)
    putStrLn $ show list4 ++ " -> " ++ show (minmax1 list4)
    putStrLn $ show list5 ++ " -> " ++ show (minmax1 list5)
```

in order to obtain the following results:

```
--   minmax1 [1,2,3] = (1,3)
--   minmax1 [1,9,3] = (1,9)
--   minmax1 [3,2,1,0] = (0,3)
--   minmax1 [100]   = (100,100)
--   minmax1 [] = (9223372036854775807,-9223372036854775808)
```

If the array is not empty, it is easy to get the values above. But when the input to `minmax1` is an empty array, how should I modify my code to obtain the value above?

Comment: Shouldn't the values in the last case be swapped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use a check for an empty list:

```
minmax1 [] = (maxBound,minBound)
minmax1 arr = (minimum arr, maximum arr)
```

Note that you do **not have to define `minBound` and `maxBound`** yourself: `Int` is an instance of `Bounded` and thus has such bounds:

```
Prelude> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
Prelude> minBound :: Int
-9223372036854775808
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pattern match on the list to see if it is empty or not:

```
minmax1 :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
minmax1 [] = (maxBound,minBound)
minmax1 arr = (minimum(arr), maximum(arr))
```

If the list is empty, the first equation will be used. If the list is not empty, the first equation is ignored and the second one will be used.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, consider a single fold over the list instead of two separate passes:

```
minmax1 = foldl' (\(a,b) c -> (min a c,max b c)) (maxBound,minBound)
```

And as an example use:

```
> minmax1 [1,5893549,192,55] :: (Int,Int)
(1,5893549)
```